# ag-grid - How to get values which are selected by user for filtering

Tags: angular, ag-grid

In ag-grid, I have enabled column filters on each column. Now when user clicks it, it shows a checkbox list with all distinct values present under that column.

User can select/deselect values, upon which the grid instantly refreshes with filtered data. I am able to get filter column names via `filterManager.allFilters` but I also need the values which are selected by user for filtering. I am not able to achieve this.

Comment: Cannot find working example for Angular, but have you tried filter events: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/#filter-events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the plunk I've created: **[Get applied values for filter](https://plnkr.co/edit/rfuVexebLf5x2q71ZZ0p?p=preview)**

Change the filter selection for `country` column and check console.

I'm using `filterChanged` event.

We get `Promise` in `params.api.filterManager.allFilters.<column>.filterPromise`, using which, you can identify it in below manner.

```js
onFilterChanged(params) {
   if (!params.api.filterManager.allFilters.country) return;

   params.api.filterManager.allFilters.country.filterPromise.then((result) => {
    console.log('##### Selected Values #####')
    const values = result.virtualList.model.model.selectedValuesMap;
    const selectedValues = [];
    for(var key in values) {
      selectedValues.push(key);
    }
    console.log(selectedValues.join(', '));
  });
}
```

Reference: [Sort & Filter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#sort-filter)

Comment: Perfect example. Let me try this solution, but I am already sure it would work.